# Handle POST input while still uploading in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to run some code while data is still being uploaded. Is it possible with Apache+PHP?

Basically, I'm trying to read from php://input before client->server upload completes. The upload itself may take several hours and I'd like to do some logging while it's working. I don't mind reading from a blocking file descriptor.

Cheers

Comment: I know you can use APC to see the progress of a file upload, and that seems to be the closest I know to what you are looking for.

Comment: Btw, are you sure your server will handle such big uploads? I don't think http protocol is best for this, compared to FTP and similar.

Answer (score 0):

No, your script does not take control until the upload has completed. The APC stuff mentioned in a comment above is limited to PHP writing out upload status to a file elsewhere on the system, which can then be read by another script to send out as progress information.

But while an upload is going, you cannot do anything with that connection until the upload completes or is aborted.

PHP is also badly suited for very large uploads - consider what happens if your link were to hiccup 10bytes from the end of that very long/large upload. Since PHP is not in control of the upload, there's no way to resume. FTP/SFTP are better suited for such things, especially since they won't delete an aborted upload.